# How hide dialog MFC?

Tags: c++, mfc, dialog, hide

I need to create dialog and button.When I click on button with arrow dialog hide, it should looks like dialog moves to top and in ahother case shows for user.
ShowWindow(SW_HIDE). I know about it. I guess to get CRect from window, change it and after that set it to ScreeToClient().
Probably somebody knows some examples with it or another ways?
thanks

Comment: By looking like it moves to the top, do you mean something like `AnimateWindow`, followed by `ShowWindow(SW_HIDE)`, and reversed for showing the window?

Comment: sorry I'm not from english speaking country
Yoiu can watch it in VS2012 Tools->Options->Environment(at left)
you see list, click again and this list hiden.I need do it like this but with dialog))
thanks cris

Comment: Why are you using MFC? There are many better (much better) alternatives, for instance Qt, http://qt-project.org.

Comment: I have to do it.That's old education program in university

Comment: @user763305 Why he uses MFC is largely irrelevant to the issue here, and 'better' is a relative term.

Comment: @user763305 Nonsense. MFC is a tool, just like a myriad other tools. Tools are neither good nor evil; they're amoral. The only question is whether they're right for the job. Sometimes MFC is right for the job and sometimes it isn't.

Comment: my teacher told me that a "tool" like .NET, Java etc. for dummys:).
It's like square, if u don't have square u can't do something.MFC more deeper.This tool carry out everything for Windows

Answer (score 0):

To hide or show a window, you use ShowWindow() as you indicated. No rectangle needed.

Otherwise, please re-explain your question, I can't make head or tails of it.

Comment: Thanks for posting
Did u see in Visual studio Tools->Options->Environment a list?When u click on Environment u see drop dowm list, my task it should be looks like this but with dialog.Probably drop-down dialog something like this.

Answer (score 0):

Normally, if you need to show a dialog that contains settings (similar to the Visual Studio "Options" dialog) then what you would typically do is this:

- List item.
- Create a CDialog-derived class.
- Create an instance of that class.
- call DoModal on that object. This shows the dialog.
- Do nothing else. Once DoModal returns the dialog has been closed.